# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ' Letter.docx'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to use docx-mailmerge to write to a word template file and when i run my program it returns this error:

"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ' Letter.docx'"

im using python 3.81 on windows 10. Please help.
Here is the part of my code that handles writing to the template.

```
document = MailMerge(template)
print(document.get_merge_fields())

print(GlobalIntro)

document.merge(Letter=GlobalIntro)
if WaitAndWatchVariable == 1:
    print(WaitAndWatchPara)
    document.merge(WaitAndWatch=str(WaitAndWatchPara))
if RestorativeTreatmentVariable == 1:
    print(RestorativeTreatmentPara)
    document.merge(RestorativeTreatment=str(RestorativeTreatmentPara))
if CrownTreatmentVariable == 1:
    print(CrownTreatmentPara)
    document.merge(CrownTreatment=str(CrownTreatmentPara))
if RootCanalTreatmentVariable == 1:
    print(RootCanalTreatmentPara)
    document.merge(RootCanal=str(RootCanalTreatmentPara))
if WisdomTeethVariable == 1:
    print(WisdomTeethPara)
    document.merge(WisdomTeeth=str(WisdomTeethPara))
if WaitAndWatchOnWisdomTeethVariable == 1:
    print(WaitAndWatchOnWisdomTeethPara)
    document.merge(WaitAndWatchOnWisdomTeeth=str(WaitAndWatchOnWisdomTeethPara))
if ExtractingTreatmentVariable == 1:
    print(ExtractionTreatmentPara)
    document.merge(ExtractionTreatment=str(ExtractionTreatmentPara))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to save or alter a document that is already opened in your screen.So in windows you need to close it first or save it somewhere else.Wrap your code in try and handle the exception.

```
try:
    ## put your whole code here##
except PermissionError:
    print('opps you need to close the file first sir')
```